# Javascript - Replace appendChild element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, image

**JS Code**

```
watermark([scope.videoSnapshotPath, scope.watermarkLogoPath])
    .image(myPositionFunction(scope.watermarkPosition))
    .then(function (img) {
    document.getElementById(scope.watermarkPosition).appendChild(img);
})
```

When user select first image, below is the result

**Output**

```
<div data-water-mark="" id="lowerRight" class="col-lg-9 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 padding-l-0">    
    <img src="data:image1/png;base64"> //first image
</div>
```

When selects any other image, the `first` image is not replaced with `second` image but gets appended.

```
<div data-water-mark="" id="lowerRight" class="col-lg-9 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 padding-l-0">    
        <img src="data:image1/png;base64"> //first image
        <img src="data:image2/png;base64"> //second image
</div>
```

How do I append images inside `div` and replace the previous image with new image selected i.e. replace first with second ?

P.S. `img src` is dynamically generated from a plugin js and solution is expected without jquery usage.

Comment: document.getElementById(scope.watermarkPosition).innerHTML = ''; document.getElementById(scope.watermarkPosition).appendChild(img);        simple way :) if you have to a single ele inside the append div

Answer (score 2):

You could change the src instead of append a new one.

```
$("#my_image").attr("src","data:image/png;base64");
```

Comment: Actually this make more sense

Comment: How do I use the above in relation with my code changing source of image ?

Comment: You just give your img an ID something like id="imageXYZ" and then you gonna replace "#my_image" with "#imageXYZ".

Comment: But the img src is generated by a third party plugin on which I do not have a control over. I can manipulate it after being appended. Pls suggest an alternate soln

Comment: If this is everytime the 1st appearance of img in this div you could use this:  `$('#lowerRight').find('img:first').attr("src","data:image/png;base64");`

Comment: JSFiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Mon5tar/j7rfgj5n/1/ click on "other Image"

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle and it works. Well, I tried like this, but the image is not generating until appended. 
`watermark([scope.videoSnapshotPath, scope.watermarkLogoPath])
 .image(myPositionFunction(scope.watermarkPosition))
    .then(function (img) {
    $('#lowerRight').find('img:first').attr("src",img);
})`

Also instead of jquery usage, can we do it angular way ? Rather if you could possibly answer this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200349/angularjs-pass-dynamic-object-value-and-call-function-from-directive

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replaceChild` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild)).

> `parentNode.replaceChild(newChild, oldChild);`

```js
var div = document.querySelector("div");
var newImg = document.createElement("img");
newImg.src = "http://placehold.it/400x150";

var swap = function(img) {
  div.replaceChild(img, div.children[0]);
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", swap.bind(null, newImg));
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150">
</div>
<button>replace</button>
```

In your code:

```
function (img) {
  var parent =  document.getElementById(scope.watermarkPosition);
  parent.replaceChild(img, parent.children[0])'
}
```

Comment: It seems, apart form the above code, I initially put `document.getElementById(scope.watermarkPosition).appendChild(img);` as well resulting in final code as `document.getElementById(scope.watermarkPosition).appendChild(img);
                        var watermark = document.getElementById(scope.watermarkPosition);
                        watermark.replaceChild(img, watermark.children[0]);`

Comment: Only putting `var watermark =  document.getElementById(scope.watermarkPosition);
  watermark.replaceChild(img, watermark.children[0])', image is not seen, or guess replace method is not working.

Comment: I've included an interactive snippet in my answer that shows how it works.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the explanation, but just like how you created image element, I too have to append `first` image and then use replace method for `second`. Is it okay or how can I replicate your snippet in my existing code ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... All added `img` elements will be accessible through the `children` property. When you use `appendChild` stuff gets added to the end (`children[children.length - 1]`). Use `insertBefore` if you want to add stuff at a custom position. Use `replaceChild` to swap out an old `img` with a new one...